# PowerShell set random Creation Date

Tags: powershell

how can i create different random creation-dates for files in a Folder?
random days, months, years and random time like Date between 01.01.1980 - 05.08.2022

```
    $files =  Get-ChildItem -force | Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer} 
foreach($object in $files)
{
     $object.CreationTime=("10 November 2016 12:00:00")
     $object.LastWriteTime=("10 November 2016 12:00:00")
     $object.LastAccessTime=("10 November 2016 12:00:00")
}
```

Comment: ```(Get-Date).AddDays(-(Get-Random -Maximum (365*30)))``` will get a random date ranging from today to about 30 years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Get-Date` to create a variable with the proper `[DateTime]` type. And you can use `Get-Random` to create random numbers in the desired range.

```
$files =  Get-ChildItem -Force -File
$Start = Get-Date '01.01.1980'
$End = Get-Date '05.08.2022'
foreach($object in $files){
    $Random = Get-Random -Minimum $Start.Ticks -Maximum $End.Ticks
    $object.CreationTime = [datetime]$Random
    $object.LastWriteTime = [datetime]$Random
    $object.LastAccessTime = [datetime]$Random
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But i need different Dates created randomly

Comment: @Cindy I updated my code suggestion. Try.